# Cut and paste not grabbing all attributes/properties from html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

I have a div that gets added dynamically to a conteneditable div; the content that gets added looks like this:

```
<div><a onclick='my_function()'>HELLO</a></div>
```

Thus, when someone clicks on HELLO, my_function will call. Works great.

But I want to allow the user to CuT this element from the contenteditable div and paste it somewhere else.

The cut and paste works as expected in the browser, with all the formatting staying consistent. But I **lose the onclick property inside the  element.** So when the user pastes the content it looks like this:

```
<div><a>HELLO</a></div>
```

Is there a way to **cut and paste content while preserving all the attributes/properties inside its html?**

I have tried using jQuery to capture the cut and paste events like this:

```
$(".editable_div").on('cut', function(event) {
     cut_content = event.currentTarget.innerHTML;
})

$(".editable_div").on('paste', function(event) {
     $(this).append(cut_content)
})
```

As well as other variations of this, ensuring 'cut_content' is globally available. Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `preventDefault()`

Demo: (ctrl + x)

```js
function my_function(){
   console.log('foo');
}

//sample function to add dynamic div
function addDynamicDiv(){
$('#firstDiv').append("<div><a onclick=\'my_function()\'>HELLO</a></div>");
}

$(document).ready(function(){
var cut_content;

$(".editable_div").on('cut', function(event) {
     cut_content = event.currentTarget.innerHTML;
     })
$(".editable_div").on('paste', function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     $(this).html(cut_content);
     })
     
$(".editable_div").on('click', function(event) {
    document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null);
});

//execute adding of dynamic div when document is ready
addDynamicDiv();

});
```

```css
.editable_div{
border: 1px solid black;
height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="firstDiv" class="editable_div" contenteditable="true"></div>
  
  <br><br>
  
  <div class="editable_div" contenteditable="true"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this replaces all content inside the div with whatever the user is pasting. If there is some other content in that div we don't want it to be replaced. The HELLO element should be pasted in independently of any other content, with its attributes preserved.